# Get Max Value in Child Table with LINQ lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

so i have data as follows (note that these table are simplified):

```
Header:    
Id    
1    
2    
3

Child:    
Id  HeaderId  Code  Round      
1   1         A     1
2   1         A     2
3   1         B     1
4   2         A     1
5   2         B     1
6   2         C     1
7   3         A     2
8   3         B     1
9   3         A     1
```

I want to count how many header that doesnt have B in their child in their max round, from data tables above the result should be 2 because:

1. Header 1 doesnt have B in round 2 (header 1 max round is 2)
2. Header 2 have B in round 1
3. Header 3 doesnt have B in round 2 (header 3 max round is 2)

this is the linq i've try

```
var result = data.Where(e =>
                 !e.Child.Any(a =>
                        a.Code == "B" &&
                        a.Round == e.Child.Max(c => c.Round))).Count();
```

but doesnt work and i got this

> ORA-00904: "Extent1"."EXPENSE_ID": invalid identifier

"Extent1"."ID" is Id column on Header table

how i can get the max Round in this case?

*-----solved, thank you-----*

Comment: Unclear what you asking, what is the exception?

Comment: So you want Header Id which doesn't have B in their max round?

Comment: @TheGeneral i need to know how many Header that doesn't have B in their child, however the condition above only for the highest round on header's child. so if the child's header have B but not on highest round, it still count

Comment: @SelvaTS yes, you're right

Comment: "but doesnt work because Id is invalid (Id on Header table)" - Please clarify this.

Comment: @SelvaTS done, edited

Comment: @TanggonJodiIsmanaI am confused, the `EXPENSE_ID` column does not exists in Header and Child table as per your sample data. And the Lambda expression is not using this column.

Comment: @SelvaTS i explained that EXPENSE_ID is id in header table in the sample data
but i edited, now everything should be matched to sample data

Comment: It seems your EF has issues. The above conditions works fine for sample data https://dotnetfiddle.net/cJ4N6w My suggestion first get the data from DB (use .ToList()) then apply this Lambda.

Comment: @SelvaTS whoa thank you, its work, my linq is not work using IQueryable, so i need to change it ToList() first then change it back using AsQueryable()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, my linq is not work because `var result` is a `IQueryable` so i need to change it to List using `.ToList()` before change it back to Queryable using `.AsQueryable()` (if needed), this is the final linq:

```
var result = data.ToList().Where(e =>
             !e.Child.Any(a =>
                    a.Code == "B" &&
                    a.Round == e.Child.Max(c => c.Round))).Count();
```

thanks to everyone who helped me

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the `Child` table. You can group the children by `HeaderId` and then find the max `Round` for each `HeaderId`, and check the children in that round for the `Code`.

```
var ans = Child.GroupBy(c => c.HeaderId)
                .Where(cg => {
                    var maxRound = cg.Max(c => c.Round);
                    return cg.Where(c => c.Round == maxRound).All(c => c.Code != "B");
                })
                .Count();
```